# Op-Amp Impdance Question

Tags: operational-amplifier, theory

[image]

For the problem shown above since there is no current travelling through the input of the Op-Amp can we assume that the Op-Amp is acting ideally? And using this assumption can we ignore the output resistances as well as A_0?

Comment: 1) zero current flowing into the input is **only one** property of an ideal opamp. 2) it is written that the opamp has an output resistance of 50 ohms. What is the output resistance of an ideal opamp?

Comment: Ideal op. amp. simplifications (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Operational_amplifier#Op-amp_characteristics) don't have to be all present or all absent. I'd disregard the characteristics not relevant to the problem (e. g. related to AC), **take into account** the ones that were **explicitly** mentioned, and use the remaining ideal properties as present. In other words: consider it an ideal op. amp except for open loop gain and non-zero output resistance.

Comment: Your instructor is correct. You did not get the right answer to this question. Consider yourself lucky that you got partial credit.

Comment: No. And no. Because of a big clue in the question.

Answer (score 0):

The op. amp. is ideal only if A0 is infinite.

The output resistance is:

r0 / (1 + Gloop)

Where Gloop is the loop gain of the circuit.

Comment:
The negative feedback of the circuit lowers r0